# DolphinDB: Single node, configuration stream data persistence is invalid

Tags: dolphindb

I added the following configuration items to dolphindb.cfg,

```
maxPubConnections=20
persisitenceDir="C:\DevTools\DolphinDB\Data\Streaming"
persistenceWorkerNum=0
maxPersistenceQueueDepth=1000
maxMsgNumPerBlock=10
maxPubQueueDepthPerSite=10
```

But when I execute the following command:

```sql
enableTablePersistence(ticks,true, true, 1000000)
```

the error shows:

```
To enable table persistence, turn on the persistence manager by specifying the configuration parameter persistenceDir for the publisher node.
```

Can I please ask what went wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use / instead of \ and remove the "" will solve the roblem.
The correct configuration is as follows:

```py
persisitenceDir=C:/DevTools/DolphinDB/Data/Streaming
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).